# BibiJs Reader not loading books with images

Tags: javascript, epub

I'm currently working on a book reading website using Bibi Reader. Some of the books, particularly those with a significant number of images, are not loading in Bibi Reader.

I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including reducing the size of the books, to rule out any potential size-related issues. However, even smaller books with images are failing to load.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Here is the [EPUB book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQkTJ-MHhoscXBQQfyJffXik_sqwzPIT/view?usp=sharing) that exhibits the problem, hoping that it might provide more context for diagnosis. I'm also attaching the loading page along with network properties that I am getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878yJ.png)